# python aiogram бот перестаёт работать во время задержки в фукнции

Tags: python, aiogram, telegram, async-await, asyncio

Пишу тг бота с отправкой доков на почту. Дело в том, что есть задержка где-то секунд 5-10(зависит от веса файла) при отправке, и на это время бот перестаёт реагировать на что-либо со стороны других юзеров. Вот как вызывается сама функция с почтой

```
await send_email(send_type, data, sub_type, user_data, file_names, all_points, end_point)
```

И как она объявлена

```
async def send_email(send_type, data, sub_type, user_data, file_names, all_points, end_point):
...
```

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Кто-нибудь знает что с этим делать? По идеи всё должно быть асинхронно, но происходит такая вот хрень. Если что на почту всё отправляется через smtp

Comment: А код функции для слабаков?

Answer (score 0):

Всё, разобрался. Я использовал обычную библу smtp вместо асинхронной aiosmtplib.